# Transfer money from US checking/saving account to NRE account

Tags: non-resident, usd-us-dollar, inr-indian-rupee

I want to transfer money from my US saving/checking account to Indian NRE account. How can I do it?
Will transferring directly from my US account to bank account will give me best rates?
or Should I use third party transfer services like click2remit for such money transfer to get best rates?